# (select > option) exact text issue using input value and :contains method in jquery

Tags: jquery, contains

My code consists of just two elements. First element is input `(#nameInput)` and second is select `(#select)`.

My goal is to check if there is `<option>` with text equal to current `#nameInput` value.

Please, take a look at the example below, if inserted text in input already exists in `option` the border of input turns red (addClass error).

But there is a issue with `:contains`, because it finds text included in the option text instead of an exact match I looking for.

As shown on example below, there are options with text `a` & `aaa`, but the error(class) appears even if `aa` or `aaaa` are inserted.

One more example, which doesn't work -> `my option` - error appears when only `my`is inserted.

```js
$("#nameInput").change(function(){ 
  var t = $(this);
  var t_val = $(this).val();

  if(
    $("#select option:contains(" +  t_val + ")" ).length
  ) { 
    t.addClass("error");
  }
  else {t.removeClass("error");}
  
});
```

```css
input, select {width:  50%; height: 32px;}
input.error {border: 5px solid red;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<input id="nameInput" type="text"/><br/><br/>
<select id="select">
  <option value="default" selected disabled>Select..</option>
  <option class="option">a</option>
  <option class="option">aaa</option>
  <option class="option">bbb</option>
  <option class="option">bbbbbb</option>
  <option class="option">my option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `input` event, `.filter()` to check if `.textContent` of `input` is equal to a `#select option` element

```js
$("#nameInput").on("input", function() {
  var t = $(this);
  var t_val = t.val();

  if (
    $("#select option").filter(function() {
      return this.textContent === t_val
    }).length
  ) {
    t.addClass("error");
  } else {
    t.removeClass("error");
  }

});
```

```css
input,
select {
  width: 50%;
  height: 32px;
}
input.error {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<input id="nameInput" type="text" />
<br/>
<br/>
<select id="select">
  <option value="default" selected disabled>Select..</option>
  <option class="option">a</option>
  <option class="option">aaa</option>
  <option class="option">bbb</option>
  <option class="option">bbbbbb</option>
  <option class="option">my option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This one is very smooth and awesome, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = $('select option').map(function(index, element){
       return $(element).text()
}).get();
console.log(arr)
$("#nameInput").keyup(function() {
  var t = $(this);
  var t_val = $(this).val();



  console.log($.inArray(t_val, arr) == -1)
  if ($.inArray(t_val, arr) == -1) {
    t.removeClass("error");
  } else {
    t.addClass("error");
    
  }

});
```

```css
input,
select {
  width: 50%;
  height: 32px;
}
input.error {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<input id="nameInput" type="text" />
<br/>
<br/>
<select id="select">
  <option value="default" selected disabled>Select..</option>
  <option class="option">a</option>
  <option class="option">aaa</option>
  <option class="option">bbb</option>
  <option class="option">bbbbbb</option>
  <option class="option">my option</option>
</select>
```

1. Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to mapp all values of select option in an array

> Description: Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

2. Use [$.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) to find match of current input value

> Description: Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

3. Use [.keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) to check values

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "keyup" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

`Change event`

```js
var arr = $('select option').map(function(index, element){
       return $(element).text()
}).get();
console.log(arr)
$("#nameInput").change(function() {
  var t = $(this);
  var t_val = $(this).val();



  console.log($.inArray(t_val, arr) == -1)
  if ($.inArray(t_val, arr) == -1) {
    t.removeClass("error");
  } else {
    t.addClass("error");
    
  }

});
```

```css
input,
select {
  width: 50%;
  height: 32px;
}
input.error {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<input id="nameInput" type="text" />
<br/>
<br/>
<select id="select">
  <option value="default" selected disabled>Select..</option>
  <option class="option">a</option>
  <option class="option">aaa</option>
  <option class="option">bbb</option>
  <option class="option">bbbbbb</option>
  <option class="option">my option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it under change event instead of keyup.

Comment: if you want change event then use change event. updated answer check change e vent